# reading data from nested json

Tags: extjs4

Its same regarding my previous post. This is the changed json I am getting from the server.

```
{"property":[{"@length":"10","@mandatory":"true","@type":"String","@label":"Description","@id":"desc"},{"@mandatory":"false","@type":"Number","@label":"Code","@id":"code"},{"@mandatory":"true","@type":"Boolean","@label":"Check","@id":"check"},{"@mandatory":"true","@type":"DateField","@label":"Date","@id":"date"},{"@mandatory":"true","@type":"List","@label":"Types","@id":"types","options":[{"@value":"eee"},{"@value":"fff"}]}]}
```

I want to render the options array of Types in a combo-box.This is the model.

```
Ext.define('Property', {

        extend : 'Ext.data.Model',

        fields : [ {
            name : 'id',
            mapping : '@id'
        }, {
            name : 'label',
            mapping : '@label'
        }, {
            name : 'type',
            mapping : '@type'
        }, {
            name : 'mandatory',
            mapping : '@mandatory'
        }, {
            name : 'length',
            mapping : '@length'
        } ],
        // {name : 'values', mapping : 'options[0].@value'}], didnt work
        hasMany : {
            model : 'Options',
            name : 'options'
        }
    });

Ext.define('Options', {
        extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
//      reader : {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'options'
            },

        fields : [ {
            name : 'value1',
            mapping : '@value'
        } ],
        associations : [ {
            type : 'belongsTo',
            model : 'Property'
        } ]
    });
```

Unable to find what is going wrong. Can someone suggest me the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into the "associations" concept in the models, and use the hasMany/belongs to relationships. IMHO, it would make it easier and cleaner code, in the same way more usefull later in the code when you will need to use the data you're trying to set.

FOr more info about association please refer to this great link in  [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.HasManyAssociation)

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

How are you configuring your combo store? If your data was fetched already you can just set the data for the combo by accessing raw data that was returned to the store.